# How do you create a UITableView programmatically with Auto Layout?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview, autolayout

It seems that it assumes you're using frames instead of Auto Layout, as you can only really init with a frame. Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You can use autolayout programmatically.
You don't need to initialize the UITableView with a frame. Instead, you have to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO`, add the table view to the parent view and then define the constraints in code.
For example:

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
NSDictionary *views =
      NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(tableView);
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:
                               @"H:|[tableView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:
                               @"V:|[tableView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
```

Please refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AdoptingAutoLayout/AdoptingAutoLayout.html to know more about the visual format. You can also choose not to use the visual format and describe the constraints programmatically.

Comment: That instantiator does not include the style setter.

Comment: I have edited my answer to fix the initialization. I didn't have XCode in front of me to test it.

Comment: That's what I figured, it still seems odd to be supplying a frame, 0 or not, when Auto Layout is the positioning system.

Comment: I get a SIGABORT with this (and the link is broken)